# FATAL ERROR: Remote side sent disconnect message in filezila

Tags: 20.04, ssh, aws, putty, filezilla

I am using FileZilla to connect my Ubuntu server using the PPK file but every time I am getting the below error. Yesterday it was working but today I tried several times but not working.

I have checked my SSH and it's working perfectly. Any idea why I am getting this error?

[image]

```
Jun 20 09:44:45 ip-172-31-11-146 sshd[11731]: Disconnected from invalid user web 136.232.79.200 port 53030 [preauth]
Jun 20 09:46:15 ip-172-31-11-146 sshd[11735]: Received disconnect from 136.232.79.200 port 49450:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 20 09:46:15 ip-172-31-11-146 sshd[11735]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 136.232.79.200 port 49450 [preauth]
Jun 20 09:47:46 ip-172-31-11-146 sshd[11740]: Received disconnect from 136.232.79.200 port 45870:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 20 09:47:46 ip-172-31-11-146 sshd[11740]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 136.232.79.200 port 45870 [preauth]
Jun 20 09:48:09 ip-172-31-11-146 sshd[11743]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from 110.226.182.195 port 10158 ssh2: RSA SHA256:zNWtw9O0p3iA02JAB8B3PB8DKDO37TtmCPDfo5he/gE
Jun 20 09:48:09 ip-172-31-11-146 sshd[11743]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Jun 20 09:48:09 ip-172-31-11-146 systemd-logind[483]: New session 69 of user ubuntu.
Jun 20 09:48:09 ip-172-31-11-146 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Jun 20 09:48:31 ip-172-31-11-146 sudo:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /var/log/auth.log
Jun 20 09:48:31 ip-172-31-11-146 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
```

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/auth.log` on the server ?

Comment: @Marco, What i have to check in that?

Comment: The log should contain the reason why the server refuses the connection.

Comment: @Marco, I have added the logs to the question. can you please check it once..

Comment: This part of the log contains your ssh login to grab the log, which is useless. We need the part of the log from the time the Filezilla connection failed.

Comment: @Marco, There are too many lines of code and I have shared the last 4-5 links of code. i have checked on this path /var/log/auth.log

Comment: @Marco, Any more help in this?

Comment: I can not help you without the needed information.

Comment: @Marco, too much code in the /var/log/auth.log server and this portal not allowing me to add

Comment: You can upload more data to a pastebin, for example [pastebin.ubuntu.com](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and post a link to it in your original question.